# Can I add visualizations related to mulitple indexes to single kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

I have two indexes which configured in kibana.

I want to display graphs from two indexes in one dashboard is kibana support this? In kibana4 and above has this but I would like to know is this supports in kiban3

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by adding an index pattern that matches the two indices, and then select this index pattern to create visualization.